# What is the correct way to import and use Apache POI in a Kotlin project?

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code, apache-poi, build.gradle

I have added the following dependencies to my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.0"
    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.0"
}
```

The output of the gradle --version command shows that I am using Gradle version 7.6.1. Additionally, the Kotlin version being used is 1.7.10 and the Groovy version is 3.0.13. The Apache Ant version being used is 1.10.11 and the JVM being used is version 17.0.6
I receive a "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" message after running the command gradle build –stacktrace.

The structure of my project is this:

[image]

And have code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

import java.io.FileOutputStream

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val workbook = XSSFWorkbook()
    val sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1")
    val row = sheet.createRow(0)
    val cell = row.createCell(0)
    cell.setCellValue("Hello, World!")

    val outputStream = FileOutputStream("example.xlsx")
    workbook.write(outputStream)
    workbook.close()
}
```

After running I a get errors:

hello.kt:1:12: error: unresolved reference: apache
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
^
hello.kt:2:12: error: unresolved reference: apache
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
^
hello.kt:7:20: error: unresolved reference: XSSFWorkbook
val workbook = XSSFWorkbook()
^
I expect to make an excel file with the cell ""Hello, World!""

P.S. I work in VSCode and would not like to try anything else

Comment: Using Kotlin with any IDE besides IntelliJ or Android Studio is just masochism. You'll have a hard time finding anyone that can help with that, because so few people are inflicting that on themselves.

Comment: Usually, source files go in a `src\main\kotlin` or `src\main\java` directory, which are the defaults expected by the Kotlin Gradle plugin. If you haven't configured in your Gradle files to point at the top level directory, you should move your code into one of those directories. But, I'm not sure how this plays out in VS... If you're determined to use VS, expect to spend many hours debugging build issues like this instead of getting to write your actual code.

Comment: Thanks. So, I downloaded and installed IntelliJ IDEA. I added the following lines to my build.gradle.kts file: implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.0" and implementation "org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.0". However, I don't understand where I should add the poi-5.2.0.jar and poi-ooxml-5.2.0.jar files.

Comment: You don’t need to add any jar files. Gradle uses Maven to download and include them in your compile path.

Comment: Cool - everything worked. How do I add a library from GitHub to the project (for example, https://github.com/VorTECHsa/refinery)?

Comment: You need the Maven group ID, artifact ID, and version. String these together with colons after the word `implementation`, like in your code block above in your `dependencies` section of your `build.gradle` file. In the case of the project you linked, I see it listed under the Packages link. In this case, you need to add to the dependencies block `implementation "com.vortexa.refinery:refinery:master.161"` and then click the button to resync Gradle.

Comment: I get an error: `untitled:main: Could not find com.vortexa.refinery:refinery:master.161`. Maybe I can clone the repository and connect it somehow?

Comment: Can you post your whole `build.gradle` file? Maybe start a new question about not being able to find the dependency since this is straying away from the question above. There are different ways to set up gradle, your project may differ depending on which wizard or tutorial you followed to create the new project. If there's a `settings.gradle` file, include that in your question, too.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help with the necessary IDE. I am creating a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75858676/how-to-configure-gradle-to-connect-to-the-repository-with-the-source-code-of-the

Comment: try `gradle clean` clean project then rebuild `gradle build`.