# How to configure Gradle to connect to the repository with the source code of the library from Github?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I have a `build.gradle.kts` file with the following code:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0"
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.0")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.0")
    implementation("com.vortexa.refinery:refinery:master.161")
}

}
```

But I'm getting an error: `untitled:main: Could not find com.vortexa.refinery:refinery:master.161`. Can I clone the repository (https://github.com/VorTECHsa/refinery) and somehow connect it?

Comment: Looks like one needs to use Github packages: https://github.com/VorTECHsa/refinery/packages/1073554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To date, what I have done is clone the https://github.com/VorTECHsa/refinery repository. Then, I deleted the test that did not pass when compiled (StringCellParserTest) and performed a Gradle build. After that, I created a new project, added the Refinery JAR files to the libs folder, and added the following code to the `build.gradle.kts` file.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.2")
    implementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1")
    implementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.19.0")
    implementation(fileTree("libs") {
        include("*.jar")
    })
}
```

The `Main.kt` file contains the following code:

```
import com.vortexa.refinery.dsl.SheetParserDefinition
import com.vortexa.refinery.dsl.TableParserDefinition
import com.vortexa.refinery.dsl.WorkbookParserDefinition
import com.vortexa.refinery.exceptions.ExceptionManager
import com.vortexa.refinery.WorkbookParser
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory 
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
import java.io.File


fun main() {
        // given
        val string = StringHeaderCell("string")
        val number = StringHeaderCell("number")
        val date = StringHeaderCell("date")
        val optionalString = StringHeaderCell("optional_str")
        val definition = WorkbookParserDefinition(
            spreadsheetParserDefinitions = listOf(
                SheetParserDefinition(
                    sheetNameFilter = { true },
                    tableDefinitions = listOf(1, 2, 3).map {
                        TableParserDefinition(
                            setOf(string, number, date),
                            setOf(optionalString),
                            anchor = "table $it"
                        )
                    }
                )
            )
        )

        val fileName = "test_spreadsheet_multitable_anchors.xlsx"
        val file = File(javaClass.classLoader.getResource(fileName)!!.file)
        val records = WorkbookFactory.create(file).use {
            WorkbookParser(definition, it, exceptionManager, fileName).parse()
        }
    print(records)
    }
```

But I am having problems with `javaClass` (I think it's a basic issue), but I won't know if the library works this way or not until I get the results. What changes should I make to the `Main.kt` code to get rid of errors and obtain the results?

Comment: The line of code 'val file = File(fileName)' helped to solve the problem related to reading data from a file. Thus, the import of the library was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this before, but this library is unconventional in that they didn't publish it to Maven Central or make it intentionally buildable by JitPack. Instead, it is only published to GitHub Packages. This makes this into a big hassle, because GitHub requires you to authenticate, even just to read public repositories.

I think it should work with JitPack though, because the page for this repository on JitPack shows it as a successful build. It just doesn't have a proper version number for the last commit that corresponds to a release version.  JitPack isn't something that the library author publishes to, so it may not have the group ID, artifact ID, or version number that the library author intended. JitPack automatically builds projects on demand using a group name based on the GitHub address.

So, to do this with Jitpack, which is the easier way:

Add to your `repositories` block in the `build.gradle` file the info for this extra Maven repository:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

And change your implementation line to use the JitPack version of this library:

```
implementation("com.github.VorTECHsa:refinery:0691ce7404")
```

Here, the version number is the commit number that corresponds with the date of their last release. It wasn't build by JitPack until just a moment ago when I requested it by clicking it on their web site. It looks like it was successful, so this *should* work.

---

To do this with GitHub packages, which is the hard way, but maybe more proper because it's what the library author intended and has the version number:

So first, you need a GitHub account. And then you need to generate a read token for your account according to the [instructions here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). Tokens expire after some time, so that's a gotcha that will bite you down the road when your project stops building and you forgot that you have to occasionally get a refreshed token. When you create the token, you should only need to check the box for `read:packages`.

Then add to your `repositories` block in the `build.gradle` file the info for this extra Maven repository:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        name = "VorTECHsa GitHubPackages"
        url = "https://maven.pkg.github.com/VorTECHsa/refinery"
        credentials {
            username = "<your github username>"
            password = "<the token you generated>"
        }
    }
}
```

Since it's not a good idea to check a token into version control, you are recommended to put your token into your system variables. Then you can reference it in Gradle like this:

```
password = System.getEnv("YOUR_GITHUB_TOKEN_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_KEY")
```

You can do the same thing with your GitHub user name if you don't want to check that into version control either.

Comment: Good afternoon. I  followed the instructions correctly and added the following code to Maven settings:
```maven {
    name = "VorTECHsa GitHubPackages"
    url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/VorTECHsa/refinery")
    credentials {
        username = "<username>"
        password = "<password>"
    }
}``` However, I'm receiving an error that says `untitled:main: Could not resolve com.github.VorTECHsa:refinery:0691ce7404`. This error message indicates that Maven is unable to find the refinery package in the specified repository. What am I doing wrong?